# What is wrong with my answer: In metric space M, If A is dense in S and B is open in S, prove $ B \subseteq \overline{A \cap B}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This was a test question. My answer:

B is open in S, so $$B \subseteq \overline{B} \subseteq S \text{(this is what was marked incorrect) }$$
A is dense in S, so $$A \subseteq S \subseteq \overline{A}$$

The rest:

$$\overline{B} \subseteq S, S \subseteq \overline{A} \rightarrow \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A} \rightarrow b \in \overline{A} \text{ }\text{ } \forall b \in \overline{B}$$

And since $$B \subseteq \overline{B}$$ we have $$B \subseteq \overline{A \cap B}$$

What is wrong with my answer? On the test my professor wrote a comment asking me how I arrived at the line in question. I don't see what the flaw in my argument is. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: My reasoning for arriving at the line is question is: B is open, so the closure of B contains B. I thought it was clear S would contain both of those sets since one of the parameters of the question is that B is open in S.

Comment: No, your teacher was right to mark this as incorrect. Every subset (open or not) is contained in its closure. But $\bar B$ has no reason to be contained in $S.$ Moreover, your final inclusion is not a consequence of the previous ones.

Comment: For $ b \in B $, find points in $ A $ very close to $ b $.

Comment: Thank you for your responses

Comment: Concretely, what if $B=S=(0,1)$ is the open unit interval in $\mathbb R$?  Is $\overline{B}\subseteq S$?